# Why my Fail2ban regex doesn't find matches?

Tags: regex, asterisk, fail2ban, regular-expressions

I have tried many regular expressions in fail2ban config, but it never return any matches.

**Line example:**

```
[2019-12-10 10:45:38] NOTICE[15077] res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c: Request 'INVITE' from '<sip:Cant@178.216.162.105>' failed for '195.154.214.141:53360' (callid: 1570242695-1186607423-1664578181) - No matching endpoint found
```

**Fail2Ban asterisk config:**

```
# Fail2Ban configuration file
#
#
# $Revision: 250 $
#

[INCLUDES]

# Read common prefixes. If any customizations available -- read them from
# common.local
#before = common.conf


[Definition]

#_daemon = asterisk

# Option:  failregex
# Notes.:  regex to match the password failures messages in the logfile. The
#          host must be matched by a group named "host". The tag "<HOST>" can
#          be used for standard IP/hostname matching and is only an alias for
#          (?:::f{4,6}:)?(?P<host>\S+)
# Values:  TEXT
#

failregex = NOTICE.* .*: Registration from '.*' failed for '<HOST>:.*' - No matching peer found

# Option:  ignoreregex
# Notes.:  regex to ignore. If this regex matches, the line is ignored.
# Values:  TEXT
#
ignoreregex =
```

**fail2ban-regex output:**

```
Running tests
=============

Use   failregex filter file : asterisk, basedir: /etc/fail2ban
Use         log file : /var/log/asterisk/messages
Use         encoding : UTF-8


Results
=======

Failregex: 0 total
|-  #) [# of hits] regular expression
|   1) [0] NOTICE.* .*: Registration from '.*' failed for '<HOST>:.*' - No matching peer found
`-

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:
|- [# of hits] date format
|  [157969] Year(?P<_sep>[-/.])Month(?P=_sep)Day 24hour:Minute:Second(?:,Microseconds)?
|  [0] (?:DAY )?MON Day 24hour:Minute:Second(?:\.Microseconds)?(?: Year)?
|  [0] (?:DAY )?MON Day Year 24hour:Minute:Second(?:\.Microseconds)?
|  [0] Day(?P<_sep>[-/])Month(?P=_sep)(?:Year|Year2) 24hour:Minute:Second
|  [0] Day(?P<_sep>[-/])MON(?P=_sep)Year[ :]?24hour:Minute:Second(?:\.Microseconds)?(?: Zone offset)?
|  [0] Month/Day/Year:24hour:Minute:Second
|  [0] Month-Day-Year 24hour:Minute:Second\.Microseconds
|  [0] TAI64N
|  [0] Epoch
|  [0] Year-Month-Day[T ]24hour:Minute:Second(?:\.Microseconds)?(?:Zone offset)?
|  [0] ^24hour:Minute:Second
|  [0] ^<Month/Day/Year2@24hour:Minute:Second>
|  [0] ^Year2MonthDay  ?24hour:Minute:Second
|  [0] MON Day, Year 12hour:Minute:Second AMPM
|  [0] ^MON-Day-Year2 24hour:Minute:Second
`-

Lines: 159081 lines, 0 ignored, 0 matched, 159081 missed
[processed in 53.87 sec]
```

What am I doing wrong?

## UPD1

It doesn't find anything even if expression is copied from log:

```
Results
=======

Failregex: 0 total
|-  #) [# of hits] regular expression
|   1) [0] \[2019-12-10 10:45:38\] NOTICE\[15077\] res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor\.c: Request 'INVITE' from '<sip:Cant@178\.216\.162\.105>' failed for '<HOST>:53360' \(callid: 1570242695-1186607423-1664578181\) - No matching endpoint found
`-
```

Also my python version is:

```
# python -V
Python 2.7.13
```

## UPD2

After a lot of tries, i made it work with this regexp:

```
failregex = NOTICE\[.+?\] res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor\.c: Request '(INVITE|REGISTER)' from '.+?' failed for '<HOST>:.*?' \(callid: .+?\) - .*
```

Answer (score 0):

> It doesn't find anything even if expression is copied from log

Fail2ban cuts the part of message matched `datepattern` out before it applies `failregex`.

BTW, your regex is worse (too many catch-all's and non greedy in addition) and a bit "vulnerable" (not anchored). Better use something like this:

```
failregex = ^(?:\[\] )?NOTICE\[\d+\] res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor\.c: Request '(?:INVITE|REGISTER)' from '[^']+' failed for '<HOST>
```

And replace `<HOST>` with more precise `<ADDR>` if your fail2ban version >= 0.10 and you don't expecting DNS names here (so IP addresses only).